# Jdeveloper intern deployment ignore Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, weblogic, jdeveloper

Since somes days i'am facing the probleme that Jdeveloper intern deployment ignore Maven dependencies.

A workaround was to copy the dependencies manually and paste them into `o.j2ee\drs\projectName\WebApp.war\WEB-INF\lib`

pom.xml

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>de.festado.alpha</groupId>
            <artifactId>dns-alpha</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I there another another possibility to solv this issue?
May be a settings in `.jpr` or `.jws` can solv the problem?
Thanks for all suggestions

Comment: Which jdev version do you use?

Comment: Do you change it from the source of the file directly, or you use Right Click > Project Properties > Libraries way!

Comment: I use right click on jsf page. The lib is in project properties check

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. I can prepare a .war file from JDeveloper and run it in tomcat. But I cannot run the application from within Jdeveloper. The libraries the application uses are not being deployed by JDeveloper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more than 2 months researches i finally find the answer.

```
 <hash>
        <list n="classPath">
          <url protocol="file" path="/${maven:maven.local.repo}de.festado.alpha-1.6.4-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
        </list>
           <value n="deployedByDefault" v="true"/>
           <value n="description" v="de.festado.alpha:1.6.4-SNAPSHOT:jar"/>
           <value n="id" v="de.festado.alpha:1.6.4-SNAPSHOT:jar"/>
           <value n="locked" v="true"/>
 </hash>
```

We need only to add

```
 <value n="deployedByDefault" v="true"/>
```

to hash Tag in the jdevelopper `.jpr` file